# Matchmaking of two users using react and firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { auth, db } from "../firebase";
import {
  getFirestore,
  doc,
  updateDoc,
  setDoc,
  onSnapshot,
  collection,
  query,
  where , and , or
} from "firebase/firestore";

const Pairing = ({data} ) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(auth.currentUser);
  const [isPairing, setIsPairing] = useState(true);
  const [pairFound, setPairFound] = useState(false);
  const fromgamesArray = [data.fromPositive, data.fromNegative];

  useEffect(() => {
    updateDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), {
      isPairing: isPairing,
    });
  }, [user, isPairing]);

  const requestPair = () => {
    if (!pairFound) {
      setDoc(doc(db, "pairRequests", user.uid), {
        requester: user.uid,
        status: "pending",
      togame: data.togame,
      fromgame:[data.fromNegative , data.fromPositive, ],
      lineId: data.lineId
      });
    }
  };

  const pairRequestsCollectionRef = collection(getFirestore(), "pairRequests");
  
  const pairRequestsQuery = query(
    pairRequestsCollectionRef,
    and(
      where("requester", "!=", user.uid),
      where("status", "==", "pending"),
      where("lineId", "==", data.lineId),
      where('fromgame', "array-contains", data.togame),
      or(where("togame" ,"==" , data.fromNegative), where("togame", "==", data.fromPositive))
    )
  );

  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(pairRequestsQuery, (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(async (requestDoc) => {
      const requestData = requestDoc.data();
      if (requestData.requester !== user.uid && !pairFound) {
        await acceptPairRequest(requestDoc.id, requestData.requester);
        unsubscribe(); 
      }
    });
  });

  const acceptPairRequest = async (requestId, requesterUid) => {
    setPairFound(true);

    // Update the status of the pair request
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "pairRequests", requestId), {
      status: "accepted",
    });

    console.log(requesterUid);

  };

  return (
    <div>
      {requestPair()}
      {pairFound ? (
        <p>A pair has been found.</p>
      ) : (
        <p>Searching for a pair...</p>
      )}
      {/* Render UI or components related to pairing */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pairing;
```

this is a matchmaking script which matches 2 users based on a criteria but the problem is that if let's say there are 2 users who are searching for a pair and then a 3rd user comes who satisfy the criteria of both the users then they both will get the pair has been found message and if there is one user searching for a pair and two users comes online then one user will accept the request of both. but i want to make pair of only two....i don't know how i can handle this problem and how should i approach this. please can anyone fix this code so that it only matches 2 users and the 3rd one should wait till another pair is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) for this, so that the changes of one user can't interfere with those of another.

Something like this:

1. Run the query you now have to find the two users to match.
   You'll want to [limit the query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) to at most two results, and only process the result if you get exactly two.
2. Start a transaction.
3. Read both documents inside the transaction, so that they become part of that transaction.
4. Check to ensure the documents still have the state from the query. If not, abort the transaction.
5. Update the documents inside the transaction.
6. Commit the transaction.

This cover the client-side code, but you'll also want to:

7. [write security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to ensure that users can only accept documents that haven't been accepted yet.

So it's a bit involved, but definitely possible.

Comment: thankyou for the suggestion but can you please look into the code once more acutally while i am using onsnapshot i only want it to accept the request of 1st user and then i am running unsubscribe() to break out of it i also tried return statement but the problem is still there....so the problem is it's accepting requests of all the users in the database and not only once it tries it multiple time the console log funciton also returns Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. that means it's trying to accept the same request multiple time.

Comment: [Limiting the query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) to two results will prevent getting 3 or more results, but it won't solve the inherent problem with your approach. The step by step guide in my answer *does* solve that problem too.